# Duration between two customer orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some difficulty with a SQL query. There is a table name Customer_Orders with the following columns

```
Order_ID INT -Primary Key  
Customer_ID INT - Customer who made the transaction  
Order_Time_Stamp DATE - Date and time of transaction
Item STRING - Description of item purchased
Transaction_Status STRING - Status can be "Success" and "Failure"
```

How can we get the duration in days between the first order and the second order for each customer within 30 days only for customers whose first order is a success?

My query logic is something like:

```
select Customer_ID, Duration_Between_Order_In_Days
from Customer_Orders
where DATEDIFF(DAYS, First_Order_Date, Second_Order_Date) < 30
and First_Order_Status='Success'
```

I have tried using DATEDIFF() function and self join and sub query, but I don't know how to find the second order for each customer. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear you don't care if second order is a success or a failure?

Comment: Mysql or sql-server - solution will be different for each?

Comment: 1. Solution required in SQL server 2. It doesn't matter if the second order is a success or failure. 3. First_Order_Date and Second_Order_Date are not direct fields, how to get them is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using adventureworks2012 [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] the first 10 records of which look like this (after resetting status of first salesorderid for customer 11000 to 0) and where 5 is equivalent to success

```
+--------------+---------------------+------------+--------+
| salesorderid | orderdate           | customerid | status |
+--------------+---------------------+------------+--------+
|            1 | 2009-10-13 00:00:00 |          0 |      0 |
|        43793 | 2005-07-22 00:00:00 |      11000 |      0 |
|        51522 | 2007-07-22 00:00:00 |      11000 |      5 |
|        57418 | 2007-11-04 00:00:00 |      11000 |      5 |
|        43767 | 2005-07-18 00:00:00 |      11001 |      5 |
|        51493 | 2007-07-20 00:00:00 |      11001 |      5 |
|        72773 | 2008-06-12 00:00:00 |      11001 |      5 |
|        43736 | 2005-07-10 00:00:00 |      11002 |      5 |
|        51238 | 2007-07-04 00:00:00 |      11002 |      5 |
|        53237 | 2007-08-27 00:00:00 |      11002 |      5 |
+--------------+---------------------+------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.18 sec)
```

Mysql

```
select f.customerid,f.firstorder,o2.`Status`,s.secondorder,o3.`status`,
        o2.OrderDate, o3.OrderDate, datediff(o3.OrderDate, o2.OrderDate) daysbetweenorders
from
(
select customerid,min(salesorderid) firstorder
from orders 
where #customerid = 11000   and 
        status = 5
group by customerid
) f
join
(
select customerid,min(o.salesorderid) secondorder
from orders o
where #o.customerid = 11000 and 
        o.salesorderid > (select min(salesorderid) from orders o1 where o1.customerid = o.customerid and o1.Status = 5)
group by customerid
) s on s.customerid = f.customerid
join orders o2 on o2.SalesOrderID = f.firstorder
join orders o3 on o3.SalesOrderID = s.secondorder

limit 10
```

Result

```
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| customerid | firstorder | Status | secondorder | status | OrderDate           | OrderDate           | daysbetweenorders |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|      11000 |      51522 |      5 |       57418 |      5 | 2007-07-22 00:00:00 | 2007-11-04 00:00:00 |               105 |
|      11001 |      43767 |      5 |       51493 |      5 | 2005-07-18 00:00:00 | 2007-07-20 00:00:00 |               732 |
|      11002 |      43736 |      5 |       51238 |      5 | 2005-07-10 00:00:00 | 2007-07-04 00:00:00 |               724 |
|      11003 |      43701 |      5 |       51315 |      5 | 2005-07-01 00:00:00 | 2007-07-09 00:00:00 |               738 |
|      11004 |      43810 |      5 |       51595 |      5 | 2005-07-26 00:00:00 | 2007-07-26 00:00:00 |               730 |
|      11005 |      43704 |      5 |       51612 |      5 | 2005-07-02 00:00:00 | 2007-07-27 00:00:00 |               755 |
|      11006 |      43819 |      5 |       51198 |      5 | 2005-07-27 00:00:00 | 2007-07-02 00:00:00 |               705 |
|      11007 |      43743 |      5 |       51581 |      5 | 2005-07-12 00:00:00 | 2007-07-25 00:00:00 |               743 |
|      11008 |      43826 |      5 |       51282 |      5 | 2005-07-28 00:00:00 | 2007-07-07 00:00:00 |               709 |
|      11009 |      43837 |      5 |       51562 |      5 | 2005-07-30 00:00:00 | 2007-07-24 00:00:00 |               724 |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
10 rows in set (0.77 sec)
```

Sql server
Very similar but status needs escaping, datediff syntax is different and top replaces limit

```
select top 10 f.customerid,f.firstorder,o2.[Status],s.secondorder,o3.[status],
        o2.OrderDate, o3.OrderDate, datediff(d,o2.OrderDate, o3.OrderDate) daysbetweenorders
from
(
select customerid,min(salesorderid) firstorder
from [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] 
where   --customerid = 11000    and 
        status = 5
group by customerid
) f
join
(
select customerid,min(o.salesorderid) secondorder
from [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] o
where   --o.customerid = 11000 and 
        o.salesorderid > (select min(salesorderid) from [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] o1 where o1.customerid = o.customerid and o1.Status = 5)
group by customerid
) s on s.customerid = f.customerid
join [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] o2 on o2.SalesOrderID = f.firstorder
join [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] o3 on o3.SalesOrderID = s.secondorder
order by f.customerid
```

Note:-Make sure you have appropriate keys - I have see mysql below (cannot guarantee these for your app).

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `SalesOrderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RevisionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrderDate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DueDate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ShipDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OnlineOrderFlag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SalesOrderNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseOrderNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SalesPersonID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TerritoryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BillToAddressID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ShipToAddressID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ShipMethodID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreditCardID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreditCardApprovalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrencyRateID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubTotal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `TaxAmt` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Freight` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `TotalDue` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowguid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedDate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY `k001` (`OrderDate`,`SalesOrderID`),
  KEY `k1` (`CustomerID`,`SalesOrderID`),
  KEY `k2` (`SalesOrderID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Customer_ID, Duration_Between_Order_In_Days

    from Customer_Orders

    where DATEDIFF(First_Order_Date, Second_Order_Date) < 30

and First_Order_Status='Success'
```

As shown in above query,try this one.

Just to care that your `First_Order_Date, Second_Order_Date` must be in form of 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I dont think he knows how to get SecondOrderdate in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Sagar but First_Order_Date and Second_Order_Date are not direct fields, how to get them is the question.